# Postgres View Returning correct rows when executing SQL, but with REST query returns one row multiple times

Tags: postgresql, rest, spring-boot, view

Morning folks, I have the following View named user_popular_photos. Let me give a bit of explanation regarding the query here. feed_item is a table and feed_item_counts is a another view which combines the number of likes from entries in another table for that specific feed_item

```
SELECT f.author,
    f.thumbnail_url,
    f.feed_id
   FROM feed_item f
     JOIN ( SELECT f2.feed_item_id,
            f2.like_count AS count
           FROM feed_item_counts f2
          WHERE f2.like_count > 0) t2 ON f.feed_id = t2.feed_item_id
  ORDER BY t2.count DESC;
```

When I run this query against the database (PGAdmin View Data - View All Rows) I get the desired results

```
author | thumbnail_url | feed_id   |
user1  | thumb 1       | feed_id 1 | 
user1  | thumb 2       | feed_id 2 |
user1  | thumb 3       | feed_id 3 |
user2  | thumb 1       | feed_id 1 |
user2  | thumb 2       | feed_id 2 | and so on...
```

However with my REST (Spring Boot) when I attempt to get the results back I get the following

```
{
  "username" : "user1",
  "popularPhotos" : [ {
    "feedId" : feed_id 3,
    "thumbnailUrl" : "thumb 3"
  }, {
    "feedId" : feed_id 3,
    "thumbnailUrl" : "thumb 3"
  }, {
    "feedId" : feed_id 3,
    "thumbnailUrl" : "thumb 3"
  } ]
}
```

Which is generated via the following;

**User.Java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotNull @NotEmpty
    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    private String username;

    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "username")
    public List<UserPopularPhotos> popularPhotos;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }   

    public List<UserPopularPhotos> getPopularPhotos(){
        return popularPhotos;
    }

    public void setPopularPhotos(List<UserPopularPhotos> popularPhotos){
        this.popularPhotos = popularPhotos;
    }
```

**UserPopularPhotos**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_popular_photos")
@Immutable
public class UserPopularPhotos {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "author", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public String username;

    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Integer feedId;

    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    @Column(name = "thumbnail_url", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String thumbnailUrl;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Integer getFeedId(){
        return feedId;
    }
    public void setFeedId(Integer feedId){
        this.feedId = feedId;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here, I can't put a finger on why the query in PGAdmin returns correct results but the API query returns the same result (top entry for that user) multiple times?

Comment: I'm guessing, but maybe because you have the `username` field in `UserPopularPhotos` annotated with `@Id`, but it's not unique.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave - Bingo, I had the `@Id` annotation on the wrong item, the `username` as indicated is not unique but the `feedId` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Id annotation is not on the unique identifier for the user_popular_photos view. Removed it from the username and added to the feedId.

**UserPopularPhotos.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_popular_photos")
@Immutable

public class UserPopularPhotos {

@Column(name = "author", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JsonIgnore
public String username;

@Id
@JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
@Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Integer feedId;

@JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
@Column(name = "thumbnail_url", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public String thumbnailUrl;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Integer getFeedId(){
    return feedId;
}
public void setFeedId(Integer feedId){
    this.feedId = feedId;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}
```

}

Making this change gives the desired return result from the API